# Setting custom R class names instead of Rcpp_ + class-name with RCpp modules

Tags: r, rcpp

I have developed a package for R using Rcpp modules. If I understand correctly, when I export a C++ class using the RCPP_EXPOSED_CLASS macro, an R class named Rcpp_[class-name] is created, and this can be used to define S3 methods as in `plot.Rcpp_[class-name]`.

How can I create a custom class name without the Rcpp_ prefix (if possible)?

(The reason of this question is that I tried to submit a description of the package to the Journal of Statistical Software, and I got the following comment back: *Wouldn't a name like "xxx" be more intuitive and easy to remember compared to "Rcpp_yyy"?*)

Comment: Do it the other way around: keep what Rcpp Modules does for you as it works, but don't export those functions but rather 'hand-crafted' ones with whatever nice naming conventions you prefer.

Comment: I agree with @DirkEddelbuettel. The user shouldn't be exposed to any Rcpp code (even indirectly). They should use your package with R classes and methods, even if they're just wrappers.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the very quick answers. Can you please clarify which functions you are recommending not to export? I am not sure I am following.